# Creating authentication using own dbcontext

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-identity, dbcontext, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to create an owin authentication using my own external sql database instead of the base asp context. I can create an edmx model from the database but i dont know how to use it to identify the users.

When i change the base Database connection used by ApplicationUser to my own one i get this exception.

[image]

I have already created at least 30 projects to test the solutions i found on google but none of them was worked for me.

Comment: I think it's not sql problem, something with multithreading

Comment: Is there an ApplicationUser table in your database? And does your own DbContext inherit from the IdentityDbContext?

Comment: Thanks for wanting to add an answer. Would you rollback to your earlier version, and post your answer using the answer box? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SOLUTION]**

The solution is much more easier than i thougth..

All i had to do was inheriting my User table from IdentityUser (AspNetUser is my own table)

```
public partial class AspNetUser : IdentityUser
```

and using my custom connectionstring's name (BCTSDb) instead of DefaultConnection in IdentityModels.cs.

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("BCTSDb", throwIfV1Schema: false)
```

This is codefirst from database, database first is not working with this solution (i dont know why).

This solved the **FIRST** problem. After this i couldn't scaffold any controllers with views because of missing keys and ambiguous references.

**[WHATTODO]**

**1. Ambiguous references**

In my AspNetUser.cs class i made all **ORIGINAL** attributes override:
for example UserName:

```
public override string UserName { get; set; }
```

Its possible that this is not necessary, i haven't tried without this, maybe this solve the ambiguous references between my dbcontext and ApplicationDbContext.

**2. Missing keys**

I dont know where i left my keys but there is the solution:

At the end of my OnModelCreating function (in my dbcontext) i wrote the following lines:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // your table operations, references
        // ...

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

After this i could do anything i want.